# Remove '.php' extension and get the id

Tags: php, .htaccess

Consider:

```
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-/]+)$ view.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-/]+)$ lista.php?category=$1 [L]
```

I remove the *.php* extension and write two rules, but clicking on different two links, the same page opens.
Only the first rewrite rule is working, but not the second rule. How can I solve it?

Comment: What do you want to achieve with this? Two rules that point to the same script, that sounds a bit strange

Comment: The original version was close to incomprehensible, but [ChatGPT](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) (or similar) will produce an answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're facing is due to the fact that both of your RewriteRules have the same pattern `(^([A-Za-z0-9-/]+)$)`. When a URL is matched against these rules, the first one will always take precedence because it's encountered first. The second rule is effectively ignored.

To resolve this, you can differentiate the patterns for the two rules. For example, you can modify the patterns like this:

```
RewriteRule ^view/([A-Za-z0-9-/]+)$ view.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^category/([A-Za-z0-9-/]+)$ lista.php?category=$1 [L]
```

Now, URLs like `example.com/view/someid` will be rewritten to `view.php?id=someid`, and URLs like `example.com/category/somecategory` will be rewritten to `lista.php?category=somecategory`.

Make sure to update your links accordingly. If you still encounter issues, you may need to check your Apache configuration to ensure that the `mod_rewrite` module is enabled and that your `.htaccess` file is being read and processed. Additionally, check for any conflicting rules or conditions in your .htaccess file or other configuration files.

Comment: Thank you but css and images not show

Comment: This answer looks like a copy-paste from ChatGPT